# Change page on every wheel event

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am having a bit hard time to solve this. Trying to change page(component) when user use wheel. These are the reference pages for what I am trying.

http://www.harukimurakami.com/

https://redredefined.preciosacomponents.com/

So I am trying to add `active` class first element, and remove it from last element every time user use wheel. But having a hard time.

```
name: 'home',
components: {
    "news-landing": newslanding,
    "news-library": newslibrary,
    "news-contact": newscontact,
},
data(){
    return {
    };
},
created () {
    window.addEventListener('wheel', this.handleScroll);
},
destroyed () {
    window.removeEventListener('wheel', this.handleScroll);
},
methods: {
    handleScroll(event) {
        const delta = Math.sign(event.deltaY);

        let classes = [];
        let nodes = [];
        classes = document.querySelectorAll(".common");
        nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(classes, 0);
        if (delta == 1) {
            nodes.forEach((item, key) => {
                if (item.classList.contains("active")) {

                }
            })
        }

    }
}
```

And this is the live code sand box:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-jr06x

Comment: please add your code here

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I added the code in the question. you can check it. @RachelGallen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your method like this:

```
handleScroll(event) {
  const delta = Math.sign(event.deltaY);

  let i;
  let nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".common");
  for(i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)
  {
    if(nodes[i].classList.contains('active'))
    {
      if(delta>0)
      {
        if(i < nodes.length - 1)
        {
          nodes[i].classList.remove('active');
          nodes[i+1].classList.add('active');
          break;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        if(i > 0)
        {
          nodes[i].classList.remove('active');
          nodes[i-1].classList.add('active');
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yes it's pretty much working. Thank you. But wheel is scrolling so fast and it's jumping to last item.  is there a way to prevent that. You can see what I meant there: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-jr06x

Comment: I am pretty sure that this depends on your mouse DPI resolution and your settings in Control Panel regarding how much lines to scroll per 1 notch of the mouse wheel. On your sandbox I am able to comfortably switch forward and backward between the 3 screens.